# Bug in NSOutlineView Delegate and OutlineCell?

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

For some reason, unless an item is a group item (`outlineView:isGroupItem` returns `YES`), the

```
   - (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView
           willDisplayOutlineCell:(id)cell 
                   forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn 
                             item:(id)item
```

method is never called in the designated `NSOutlineView` delegate, even when the item is expandable and `outlineView:shouldShowOutlineCellForItem:` for the item returns `YES`. This seems like a bug to me. Any idea if this is the intended behavior? If so, how can I work around it to change the disclosure triangle?

**Environment:**

Xcode 4.2

OS X Lion 10.7.2

Comment: Same here, did you manage to figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me. You should break your code down to the simplest possible example, you're probably seeing an unintended consequence of some other code in your datasource or delegate.